# Comment support for Sass files in WebStorm/PhpStorm

Tags: sass, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to get WebStorm/PhpStorm to support the `/**` comment notations in a `.scss` file.

In a `.js` file for example when you type `/**` and go to the next line, the IDE will automatically close the comment, and add a comment line e.g:

```
/**
 *   < Automatically added
 */  < Automatically added
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality if not currently supported for `.scss` files (or any other CSS-alike files).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6795 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

**P.S.** Try pinging devs in the ticket -- see what they have to say about current status .. because so far it's not planned to be implemented for any specific version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you know of the correct channel to @mention?

Comment: You mean -- on the Issue Tracker/ticket? The assigned developer is `Assignee: Alexander Zolotov` .. simply typing `@` in the comment box lists him as first entry (`@zolotov`)